# Run Time Check Error # 2

Tags: c++

```
#include <string.h>

#include "BubbleSort.h"

void BubbleSort(char Str[])
{
    int     i;
    int     NumElements;
    bool    Sorted;
    char    Temp;

    NumElements = strlen(Str);
    do {
        Sorted = true;
        NumElements--;
        for (i = 0; i < NumElements; i++)
            if (Str[i] > Str[i + 1])
            {
                Temp = Str[i];
                Str[i] = Str[i + 1];
                Str[i + 1] = Temp;
                Sorted = false;
            }
    } while (!Sorted);
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////

#include <iostream>
#include "Bubblesort.h"

using namespace std;



void main() {
    int  Num; 
    char  Array[20]; 



    cout << "How many numbers would you like to enter?" << endl;
    cin >> Num;

    cout << "Enter your numbers:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < Num; i++) 
    {
        cin >> Array[i];
    }


    cout << "Here are the numbers you entered:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < Num; i++) 
    {
        cout << Array[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl << endl;

    BubbleSort (Array); 


        cout << "Here are your sorted numbers:" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < Num; i++)
        {
        cout << Array[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#ifndef BUBBLE_SORT_H
#define BUBBLE_SORT_H

void BubbleSort(char[]);

#endif
```

I get a Run Time Error stating that Num was corrupted. Can anyone help pinpoint the problem in my code?

Thanks

Comment: What's your input?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please re-format your code properly and read [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask questions.

Comment: `main` can not be `void`

Comment: @MiloLu some compilers accept it but it's a very bad habit. It's not standard.

Answer (score 0):

`char Array[20]` while the `Num` you input is larger than 20, it will corrupt.

Better use `vector` and `push_back`

Answer (score 0):

One mistake is that you're calling `strlen` on a char array that is not guaranteed to be NULL terminated:

`NumElements = strlen(Str);`

Thus `NumElements` has an undetermined value.

You need to either:

1) pass the actual number of characters that are to be sorted as a parameter, along with the array and getting rid of the call to `strlen`:

```
BubbleSort(Array, Num);
//...
void BubbleSort(char Str[], int NumElements)
```

or

2) Make sure the char array you're passing is null terminated